# Google recaptcha not working on server, but working on localhost

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I want to access googles recaptcha v2 api with curl but it only works on my localhost.The error is "**SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK**".When somehow I manage to bypass this, it gives me a **301 Moved Permanently** error which leads to **404 error** and  **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);** doesn't resolve this problem. Another strange thing is the **namelookup_time** is more than 15 seconds aka really slow.

I've tried disabling CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST ,adding cacert.pem file and all other CA bundles but it still doesn't work. The problem is obviously connected with the SSL certificates but I've tried everything there was on the internet. Another useful thing might be to say that on my server the curl is a little old, as well as everything else.

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
url_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'secret' => $mysecret,
        'response' => $mycaptcha,
    )
```

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I said that I downloaded and added the certificate bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the bind of the server. It was lagging and this was causing the slowness and the impossible connection, after a restart everything works as it should. Hope that this will help to someone!